# Memory Allocator - Simple Segregated Storage: how do you infer the size of an allocated block from its address?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am reading the CS:APP book and I stumbled upon `Simple Segregated Storage` in the `Dynamic Memory Allocation` chapter.
The book mentions that one of the advantages of `Simple Segregated Storage` is that the memory blocks do not need a header. It mentions

> Since each chunk has only same-size blocks, the size of an allocated block can be inferred from its address

Image from the book - [CS:APP - Simple Segregated Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbHzC.png)
I am failing to understand how this works. I understand that since the size of blocks is equal for a single free list, the address of each block would be incremented by the same amount initially when a large block is requested from the kernel and divided but how can we infer the size from the address? It has to be a multiple of the block size but if the initial starting address is not, then it will never be a multiple of the block size. Moreover, if the size classes go, 2, 4, 8, 16, the address can be multiples of many other size classes?

Comment: It says *... the same-sized blocks in each chunk...* If you have all blocks of size M in a single allocated memory chunk, you can know from the address of the block which memory chunk it is in, and so it its size M.

Comment: The memory allocation software simply sets up regions of memory. For example, 0x1000000 to 0x2000000 is used for eight-byte blocks, 0x2000000 to 0x3000000 is used for 16-byte blocks, 0x3000000 to 0x4000000 is used for 32-byte blocks, and so on. Or, perhaps more realistically, each time the software needs a new region of memory, either because a new size was requested or an old region is full, it allocates a bunch of memory, remembers where it starts and what size it is for, and uses it only for blocks of that size. Then `free` looks up returned blocks in the remembered start addresses.

Comment: It goes on to talk about a linked list of free (available) blocks. When a memory block is needed, it it taken from the head of the linked list (for that block size), and when it is released, it becomes the head block of the linked list.

Comment: @EricPostpischil only thing is that `Simple Segregated Storage` doesn't embed any of those information in the memory blocks. The book mentions that it does not need a header or footer
It says it can do so because "the size of an allocated block can be inferred from its address" which is the part that baffles me. How can you infer the size from the address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An allocator using this approach acquires large blocks (chunks) of memory from the OS.  It designates a block size to use for allocating blocks out of each chunk, and the key to "simple segregated storage" is that *every allocation from a given chunk will be **exactly** the same size*.  That may be more than the requested size for any given request, but that's not uncommon for allocators generally.  To determine the (true) size of a given allocation, then, the allocator needs only to determine which chunk it resides in.  It does not need any per-allocation information.

Comment: I understand the allocator only needs to know which chunk (free list) the allocated block should go back to when freeing but how does it know that from the address of the allocated block?  
I know the blocks in the same chunk have the same size but I am not sure how that helps when the chunk (free list) could start at a random memory location

Comment: @BSE10, it has, somewhere, chunk-level records of the base address and size of each chunk.  Or equivalently, the start and end addresses of each chunk.  It does not need *per-allocation* headers, but it still needs *some* metadata.

Comment: If that's the case, then the blocks can be of any size within the size class range and you can still know which chunk the block belongs to if you are just comparing the block address to chunk start and end addresses.
The book specifically mentions the reason is because the blocks in the same chunk have equal sizes and that's why the size can be inferred from the block's address. This is the part I am trying to understand

Comment: @BSE10, yes, the whole point is that the address of an allocated block tells you to which chunk it belongs.  And because all the blocks allocated out of a given chunk are exactly the same (true) size, that tells you the size of the allocation.  And *that* is why, with this scheme, you don't need to maintain per-allocation records of allocation size.

Comment: Ah ok. Now it's making a lot more sense
Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I totally understand what you mean, because I try to use this method in malloclab and find this problem.

I agree that we can't calculate the block size from address, if the address&(4KB-1) is 32, it could be the 5th for 8, 3rd for 16 or 1st for 32. And if the address is 0, it could be the first block for any size.

So we must use extra space to record some info.

One solution is recording each chunk start address and which free list it belongs to, then if we get the free address void* ptr, search (ptr & ~4KB) in the chunklist to find the corresponding block size. But that's so stupid and hard to code.

Another solution is adding header. And I choose to finish in this way.